# Does OS X 10.7 libc++ support c++14?

Tags: c++, macos, osx-lion, c++14, libc++

I'm updating a project to use the latest Qt and taking the opportunity to switch to libc++ and C++11 at the same time. My understanding is that OS X 10.7 and above support this without me needing to ship my own build of the standard library. I'm happy to no longer support OS X versions <10.7.

C++11 support is great, but I'd really like to use C++14.

Does the libc++ installed for end-users with OS X >10.7 also support C++14 standard library features?

My guess is 'Yes' and that it's kept up to date by OS updates in >10.7 - but I've been unable to find a definitive source stating this to be the case.

Comment: It's an interesting question as C++14 support has only just been added to the Xcode 6.3 compiler AFAIK.  It might depend how much functionality is provided by the compiler and how much by the runtime library.  I'd be interested in hearing a good answer here.

Comment: Yes, it also depends whether the new C++14 standard library additions are purely templates (i.e. make_unique) or whether there's anything that actually needs to be built into a dynamic library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not. Apple shipped the last update for Mac OS X 10.7 (10.7.5) in October 2012; it's unlikely that the libc++.dylib has been updated since then (the only exception that I could think of is for security issues)

Xcode ships with a set of headers that change with what SDK you target; if you target a particular system (say 10.7), you get those headers.

Compare the contents of `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/` and `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/` too see what I mean.

For template-only features, you could use your own set of headers from a later LLVM release - but then you would be taking the burden of ensuring compatibility upon yourself.

Comment: Thanks Marshall, that makes sense. Especial thanks for pointing out that although I could use my own headers with the template-only features, the resulting code may not necessarily be compatible with the installed standard library runtime. For now I'll stick to C++11 and I'll weigh up the cost/benefits of shipping my own build of the standard library some time in the future.

Comment: Side note: I've been primarily a windows developer in the past and am used to just shipping along with the microsft provided runtime redistributable for the compiler version I'm using. It seems things are not so simple in the Apple world!

Comment: Well, if you target 10.7 (say), you get an executable that will run on 10.7 and later - but can't access the new features in 10.8.

Comment: When you put it like that.... yeah OK that's pretty much as straightforward as you can get :)